# Is there a way to access the current focal distance of camera under auto focus mode using Camera2 API?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am using Auto focus mode and I want to get the current focal distance. I used `LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE`, and it was always showing 0.22 as I was moving the camera and changing the focal plane. Is there a way to check the current focal distance of the camera?

in my code I have:

```
float yourMinFocus = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
float yourMaxFocus = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_HYPERFOCAL_DISTANCE);
                                
 Log.e("hello",String.valueOf(yourMinFocus3));
```

and it is continuously losing out 0.22 no matter how I changed the focal plane.

Answer (score 0):

This is available if the camera device is capable enough, via the `LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE` value in [CaptureResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult?hl=en#LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE).

The values you're referring to are in CameraCharacteristics, which is just static information about the device. None of them change during operation. The minimum focus distance is just the closest distance the camera can focus, and the hyperfocal distance is [just that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfocal_distance).